# C executing function before or after operator call? Redefining operators?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm working on writing memory manager(s) for both C and C++.  C doesn't support function overloading so to compensate for for redefining malloc, I've used a style such as:

```
void * my_malloc(size_t size) {
    void * p = malloc(size);
    // Do additional stuff
    ...
}

#define my_malloc(x) malloc(x)
```

Which lets me call my `malloc` with `malloc(sizeof(type))`.  This works.  However, I'd also like to do things when operators are called, preferably after an assignment operation takes place.  I know that GCC supports `__attribute__((destructor))`.

So my question is, is there a way to execute a function before/after an operator is called (preferably also being passed the parameters) or can operators be redefined using macros?

Comment: Using the pre-processor in this way is a terrible idea.  It leads directly to things like C++!

Comment: @WilliamPursell Note that C++ doesn't kill as many kittens as most people believe though :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function overloading is just syntactic sugar. There's nothing special about them. All you really need is to use my_malloc() without defining any macro.  If you need to switch back to malloc(), *then* you define a macro:

```
#define my_malloc(x) malloc(x)
```

Operator overloading is also just syntactic sugar. You can introduce functions that do the operation. The only difference is that in C++ the function is, for example, named "operator+" while in C you must name it something like "add()". Nothing special about it.

Let's take the assignment operator as an example. In C++, the function would be named "operator=()". In C, you'd just use "assign_sometype()" that takes two arguments a and b and assigns a to b (or vice versa). So in C++ you'd have:

```
a = b;
```

in C that would be:

```
assign_sometype(a, b);
```

For the equality operator (`==`), you'd use "equals_sometype()" which compares its two arguments and returns true of false. So if in C++ you have:

```
if (a == b) // ...
```

then in C that would be:

```
if (equals_sometype(a, b)) // ...
```

(Remember to use pointers as arguments as appropriate.)

It's the same thing, it's just written differently with C++ trying to make it look more natural. And note that many C++ programmers don't like operator overloading very much. I'm not too keen of it myself. It does help readability on some cases, but it can also be horribly abused. (You can find many articles on abusive operator overloading if you search the net.)

Comment: The function overloading was just an example.  I'm looking for a way to do a similar thing with operators.

Comment: @hkpeprah Operator overloading is also just syntactic sugar. Updated my answer.

Comment: So there's absolute no way to do it for the equal `=` operator?

Comment: @hkpeprah That's the assignment operator. In C++ the function would be named "operator=()". In C, you'd just use "assign_sometype()" that takes two arguments a and b, and assigns a to b (or vice versa). For the equality operator, you'd use "equals_sometype()" with compares its two arguments and returns true of false. So if you have "a == b" in C++, you have "equals_sometype(a, b)" in C. It's the same thing, it's just written differently.

Comment: Macros without arguments are more invasive than macros with arguments.  If you have `#define my_malloc malloc`, there is no way to avoid the macro other than `#undef my_malloc`.  If you have `#define my_malloc(s) malloc(s)`, then you can write the code for `my_malloc` as `void *(my_malloc)(size_t s)` and even with the macro in scope, the reference to `my_malloc` there is not an invocation of the `my_malloc` function-like macro because the next symbol is not an open parenthesis.  Use function-like macros in preference to plain macros — especially when you're mapping a function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh wow. I didn't know that in this case the preprocessor doesn't just do blind text replacement regardless of parentheses. The way I've always done this is `#ifdef USE_MY_MALLOC void* my_malloc(size_t s); #else #define my_malloc malloc`. Thanks for commenting on it!